# Select specific columns of table and relation in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

Lets consider I have a Model `User` and another Model `Employee`

Now I want to pluck only some fields of Employee model such as **salary, id, emp_id** along with some columns of User model such as **name,id**.

```
$employee = Employee::with('user:id,name')
             ->where('department', $request->department)
             ->get(['id', 'emp_id', 'salary']);
```

When I execute this it will return **id,emp_id,salary** data but for **user:name,id** it will return **null**

How can I also specify **user:id,name in get()** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either load the full model or only some fields of it. To only load some fields, use `select()`. It also works within the relationship eager loading query:

```
$employees = Employee::with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'employee_id', 'name']);
    }])
    ->where('department', $request->department)
    ->select(['id', 'emp_id', 'salary'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: this is not working still. It gives error saying user.name column not found

Comment: @Raj What exactly is your desired output? An array with the five columns or the models with only these five properties loaded?

Comment: I need a model to be returned from it which I can use in view

Comment: This returned the last select columns: ['id', 'emp_id', 'salary'] but for relation user it returned null: user:null

Comment: You might need to add `employee_id` to the select list for the user, otherwise Eloquent cannot match them. Fixing it in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

use [`select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects) method from Query bulider:

```
$employee = Employee::with('user')   // or users <---
                    ->select(['id', 'emp_id', 'salary', 'users.id AS user_id', 'users.name AS username'])
                    ->where('department', $request->department)
                    ->get();
```